# Retrieving image data from gridFS storage

Tags: node.js, express, multer, gridfs

I'm trying to retrieve data with express router with below code.
The idea is to combine the json data from Dermoscopy model with the image data that was initially stored using multer and gridfs storage.
So the front-end will receive data containing : caption, data, filename, and the imagedata

Somehow the photodata doesn't contain the imageData. How do I fix this ?

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Dermoscopy = require('../models/photo_dermoscopy.model');
let PhotoFile = require('../models/photouploads.files.model');
let PhotoChunks = require('../models/photouploads.chunks.model');

router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
        Dermoscopy.find({ sessionId: { $eq: req.params.id }})
            .then(photo_dermoscopy => {
                const photodata = [];

                photo_dermoscopy.map(item => {
                    var imageData = PhotoFile.find({filename:item.filename})
                    .then(doc => {
                        PhotoChunks.find({files_id: doc[0]._id}).then(item => {
                            let fileData = [];
                            for (i=0; i< item.length; i++) {
                                fileData.push(item[i].data.toString('base64'));
                            }
                            let image = 'data: '+ doc[0].contentType + ';base64,' + fileData.join('');   
                            return image;
                        })
                        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));  

                    photodata.push({caption: item.caption, date: item.datetaken, filename: item.filename, photo: imageData})
                })
                res.send(photodata)
                })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `imageData` when it is available meaning:

```
photodata.push({caption: item.caption, date: item.datetaken, filename: item.filename, photo: imageData})
```

The above code executed before fetching the `PhotoFile` and it is `undefined`. You should add the data in the `PhotoFile` promise.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Dermoscopy = require('../models/photo_dermoscopy.model');
let PhotoFile = require('../models/photouploads.files.model');
let PhotoChunks = require('../models/photouploads.chunks.model');

router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
        Dermoscopy.find({ sessionId: { $eq: req.params.id }})
            .then(photo_dermoscopy => {
                const photodata = [];

                photo_dermoscopy.map(item => {
                    var imageData = PhotoFile.find({filename:item.filename})
                    .then(doc => {
                        PhotoChunks.find({files_id: doc[0]._id}).then(item => {
                            let fileData = [];
                            for (i=0; i< item.length; i++) {
                                fileData.push(item[i].data.toString('base64'));
                            }
                            let image = 'data: '+ doc[0].contentType + ';base64,' + fileData.join('');   
                             photodata.push({caption: item.caption, date: item.datetaken, filename: item.filename, photo: imageData})
                            return image;
                        })
                        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
                    })
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));  

                    
                })
                res.send(photodata)
                })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

You can also use `async/await`, it provides better readability.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Dermoscopy = require('../models/photo_dermoscopy.model');
let PhotoFile = require('../models/photouploads.files.model');
let PhotoChunks = require('../models/photouploads.chunks.model');

router.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
       try {  
        const photo_dermoscopy = await Dermoscopy.find({ sessionId: { $eq: req.params.id }})
        const photodata = [];
        photo_dermoscopy.map(item => {
            
            const imageData = await PhotoFile.find({filename:item.filename})        
            const item = await PhotoChunks.find({files_id: doc[0]._id})
            let fileData = [];
            
            for (i=0; i< item.length; i++) {
                fileData.push(item[i].data.toString('base64'));
            }
           
            let image = 'data: '+ doc[0].contentType + ';base64,' + fileData.join('');   
            photodata.push({caption: item.caption, date: item.datetaken, filename: item.filename, photo: imageData})
            return image;
            });
            res.send(photodata);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
})
```